# How to deploy application to streamlit using conda and environment.yml file?

Tags: python, dependencies, conda, environment, streamlit

I have a streamlit application and an environment.yml file. This is a snippet of what the file looks like:

```
name: multivarPrphoetVar2
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - streamlit==1.8.1
  - pystan==2.19.1.1
  - fbprophet==0.7.1
  - pip
  - pip:
    - plotly==4.14.3
```

Locally, the application is booting and working without issues. On steamlit cloud, I get errors which are not explanatory.
These are the errors from streamlit:

```
[32m[manager] [0minstaller returned a non-zero exit code
[32m[manager] [0mError during processing dependencies! Please fix the error and push an update, or try restarting the app.
[32m[manager] [0mStreamlit server consistently failed status checks
[32m[manager] [0mPlease fix the errors, push an update to the git repo, or reboot the app.
```

How to fix those?

Comment: I believe folks in the community forum may help you debug that. See https://discuss.streamlit.io/c/streamlit-sharing/13